# Hide virtual keyboard on EditText focus lost

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked million times, but I'm not able to find a direct solution for my specific problem.

In my SearchActivity, there is a `EditText` & a `ListView`.

I want even if the user touches anywhere except EditText, the keyboard should close.

What I've done is setup a `TouchListener` on ListView & whenever it is touched, the keyboard is closed.

But it is creating a problem that when I touch on any element of the ListView, the keyboard hides, but the element of the list becomes invisible.

Please suggest a better approach than this.

My Code:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    RelativeLayout rlSearchLayout;
    EditText etSearchBar;
    ListView lvSearchResult;
    private static String searchText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        setTitle("SearchActivity.java");

        etSearchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchBar);
        lvSearchResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearchResult);

        searchText = etSearchBar.getText().toString();
        lvSearchResult.setOnTouchListener(this);

        String[] objects = { "One", "two" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
        lvSearchResult.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etSearchBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an `imageView` with **transparent** image as activity background and implement `TouchListener` for that `imageView`.

Comment: thanks for reply, but can you show how to make an image cover the entire layout & how to make it transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your layout file.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    />
```

Now add a `TouchListener` for this `imageView` in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Your EditView>.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        If(!hasfocus)
          hideSoftKeyboard()
    }
});
```